# How to update a property in a coffeescript class

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to update a property with the following code when I call the "scanner.connect()" method:

```
class Scanner
    ready: false

    connect: () =>
        cordova.exec (status) =>
            console.log status
            if status is 'connected'
                @ready = true
                console.log @ready
        ,
        (error) ->
            console.log error
        ,
        "LineaProScanner", "ready", []

    scan: () ->
        console.log 'start scan...'
    stop: () ->
        console.log 'stopping scan...'
```

Then when I access the scanner.ready property it always shows false.

```
scanner = new Scanner()
scanner.connect()
console.log scanner.ready // always shows false
```

I'm just starting with CoffeeScript so I know I'm doing something wrong haha but I'm just not sure what.

Thanks!

Comment: oh and yes the status returns "connected" I checked heh

Comment: Why is `connect` using a fat arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coffeescript looks fine, its the order of execution that's to blame here, an issue that trips up plain ol' JS programmers a lot too.

I'm betting `cordova.exec()` is async, so you are asking if it's ready before it calls back and sets the ready.

Try this to see if I'm right:

```
scanner = new Scanner()
scanner.connect()
setTimeout (-> console.log scanner.ready), 1000
```

That should log `true` so long as the scanner readies itself in less than one second. But that's not how you should structure this code.

---

The right way, is instead of this `setTimeout` you want your own callback instead.

```
class Scanner
    ready: false

    # Accept a callback argument on the connect method.
    connect: (onReady) =>
        cordova.exec (status) =>
            console.log status
            if status is 'connected'
                @ready = true
                console.log @ready

                # call the onReady callback if it was passed in
                onReady?()
        ,
        (error) ->
            console.log error
        ,
        "LineaProScanner", "ready", []
```

And now you can simply do:

```
scanner = new Scanner()
scanner.connect ->
  console.log scanner.ready # should log `true`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the `=>` on this line :

`connect: (onReady) ->`

Class methods can access directly to class variables. But functions inside methods do not.